# MySQL: #1054 - Unknown column 'product_type' in 'field list', but there is no such column in the query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I am trying to execute the following insert query.

```
INSERT INTO product_records( p_id, color, brand, product_line ) 
VALUES (
'8',  'test',  'test',  'test'
)
```

but it says,

```
MySQL: #1054 - Unknown column 'product_type' in 'field list'
```

**EDIT:**
Table- **product_records**

```
Field   Type    
p_id    varchar(10)
color   varchar(32)  
brand   varchar(15)  
product_line    varchar(32)
```

But there is no column 'product_type' in table  `product_records`. whats wrong here, i have no idea!

Comment: Can you show us the table schema of product_records?

Comment: what is the dataType of p_id..

Comment: Do you have a computed column on the table?

Comment: @Rajneesh071, type of p_id is varchar

Comment: @PreetSangha, there is no computed column. this is a very simple mysql table.

Comment: How about triggers?  If there are triggers it could be an undeclared variable that is being mis-diagnosed as a "column". There's an old bug describing this but I can't find it right now.

Comment: may be you are accessing wrong table....just chk its name...

Comment: Found it: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26394